# Get source function of lambda expression with captured variable

Tags: python, function, lambda

Having a lambda function that uses a regex:

```
import re

def make_func(pattern = "black.*"):
    func = lambda x: re.fullmatch(pattern, x)
    return func
```

I would like to retrieve the source function including its `pattern` for error reporting. The expected output would be something like:
`func = lambda x: re.fullmatch("black.*", x)`

Knowing of the inspect module and the function *getsource*, I managed to solve part of my problem, but the `pattern` variable is not evaluated:

```
from inspect import getsource
print(getsource(func))
```

which yields `func = lambda x: re.fullmatch(pattern, x)`. How can I get the concrete `pattern` that was captured by the function as well?

Comment: Why would you wanna do this?

Comment: Using `get_source(func)` with a default pattern parameter in your lambda function `func = lambda x, pattern = "blackish.*": re.fullmatch(pattern, x)` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: What you got *is* the source. How its variables are resolved is far from trivial and amounts to (partial) compilation, something that is really hard to do correctly for Python. Do you have any constraints to simplify this, for example that so variables are in the same scope and will not be modified?

Comment: The `func` is passed to a general filter function. I can't place the regex matching in there, that would make it too specific, since other fields might be checked / matched as well. 
The pattern is a user input, so not known and therefore must be a variable.
Finally, I need to raise an Error if the pattern was not found, but would prefer to tell the user which pattern did not match. At the moment the message simply says something like "I could not find func = lambda x: re.fullmatch(pattern, x)". More helpful would be to pattern compiled in that message.

Comment: @not_a_robot This seems as if you should use a totally different approach. Given the user input (which you have at some point) create an *object* that stores the pattern and the equivalent of `func` (this could be just a method that uses the pattern). […]

Comment: […] If you want to stick to having a `lambda` *and it is created in a local scope*, then inspecting the `lambda`'s function object to retrieve the closure is heaps better than the source (the latter which is impossible for this task – the input is not in the source). If the `lambda` is in a global scope, then you should change your design anyway since the pattern is not safe against modification.

Comment: That (separate  object that stores the function along with its arguments) is indeed something I had in mind, but was hoping that there might be a *straighter* way of doing so. But sounds like getting a partially compiled function definition is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: The `lambda` is in a local scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for *exactly*, but I think there are several ways to achieve what you want.

For example, you could store the pattern inside the lambda function object that you return, or update its docstring:

```py
def make_func(pattern='black.*'):
    func = lambda x: re.fullmatch(pattern, x)
    # Option 1:
    func.pattern = pattern
    # Option 2:
    func.__doc__ = f'lambda x: re.fullmatch({pattern!r}, x)'
    return func
```

Using either of this options, the used pattern is still available in the function object so it can be used for error reporting.
Note that this is bit hackish, and I'm not sure if this might cause problems in the long run.

By the way: assigning a lambda expression is an anti-pattern (see pycodestyle/flake8 rule [E731](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E731.html) and/or [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)). You could just as well define and return a function:

```py
import re

def make_func(pattern='black.*'):
    def func(x):
        return re.fullmatch(pattern, x)
    func.__doc__ = f're.fullmatch({pattern!r}, x)'
    return func

func = make_func()
print(func.__doc__)  # prints: re.fullmatch('black.*', x)
```

I think a nicer and more Pythonic solution is to create a callable object, which could be used as a function but also incorporates the original pattern:

```py
import re

class FullPatternMatcher:

    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    def __call__(self, x):
        return re.fullmatch(self.pattern, x)

    def __str__(self):
        return f're.fullmatch({self.pattern!r}, x)'


def make_func(pattern='black.*'):
    return FullPatternMatcher(pattern)


func = make_func()
# just to demonstrate that the function is working:
assert func('white sheep') is None
assert func('black sheep') is not None
print(str(func))  # prints: re.fullmatch('black.*', x)
```

Finally, you could also use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which has roughly the same effect as above solution, but using the standard library instead of a custom class. In this case the pattern is stored as `args[0]` inside the returned object:

```py
import functools
import re

def pattern_match(pattern, x):
    return re.fullmatch(pattern, x)

def make_func(pattern='black.*'):
    return functools.partial(pattern_match, pattern)

func = make_func()
print(repr(func.args[0]))  # prints: 'black.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where pattern is defined, you can use `inspect.getclosurevars` to get the variables, they should be in globals or nonlocal. It might be really hard to generalize and I' pretty sure you can achieve your end goal in a better way.

Example:

```py
import inspect

x = lambda bar: print(foo + bar)
inspect.getclosurevars(x)
```